# C++: reading an int from a binary istream without using an uninitialised variable

Tags: c++, io, stl, binary, istream

As best as I can determine, the most common way to read an `int` from a binary `istream` is as follows:

```
int32_t s;
istr.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&s), sizeof(int32_t));
```

But this separates the declaration and initialisation of the variable, which is generally not considered idiomatic in C++. It's easy to wrap the above up in an inline function that reads and returns the `int32_t`... but it seems surprising that this hasn't been provided by the standard library.

Am I missing something? Is there a standard library function out there that reads and returns an `int` from an `istream`?

Comment: There's a concept here which is a thorn, called *Endianness*.  Some platforms are Little Endian, others are Big Endian.  Big Endian formatted data read by a Little Endian platform is a nasty bug.  However, a textual representation of an integer can be read regardless of the Endianness of the platform.

Comment: Also, not all platforms are 32-bit.  There are many 8-bit and 16-bit platforms out there.  So I'm guessing that the C++ committee doesn't want to deal with the variations in platforms when implementing a binary (no translation) input from a stream.

Comment: Have you tried writing your own function that returns an `int32_t` from a binary stream?  What happens when there is a fault or exception with the read?

Comment: Also, to reduce the size of the standard libraries, a function that can read one or more bytes can also be used to read in a 4-byte integer as well as a 26-byte structure.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews these are fair points. I did use `int32_t` rather than `int` for a reason, and I'm aware of the endianness issue.  But generally if you are using C++ rather than another language it's because efficiency of one kind or another matters --- and sometimes that means using binary I/O rather than text. Regarding the library size point specifically, I think this is a bit of a red herring as unused code can be stripped out.

Comment: Regarding the fault/exception: is there a reason why reading an `int` is different from reading a `char` (which is supported by `get`)?  Actually, it occurs to me that reading a char is not, strictly speaking, portable either...